# Rename the download pdf file using swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pspdfkit

I am successfully downloading a PDF from api end point. Once pdf is downloaded, the title of pdf is : PDF document.pdf .
How to change the title of PDF?

I tried to update `metadata` of PDF using `PDFDocumentAttribute` (see below), but it is not working.

```
var metadata = pdfDocument.documentAttributes!
metadata[PDFDocumentAttribute.subjectAttribute] = "subject attribute"
metadata[PDFDocumentAttribute. titleAttribute] = "title attribute"
pdfDocument.documentAttributes = metadata
```

Note: I am not using `FileManager`

How I am fetching PDF:-

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, _, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let unwrappedData = data, error == nil else {
                    completion(.failure(error ?? Constants.dummyError))
                    return
                }

                guard let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: unwrappedData) else {
                    completion(.failure(error ?? Constants.dummyError))
                    return
                }

                completion(.success(pdfDocument))
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you download it? Isn't that the name of the file, as it's its path?

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your comment. I've updated question description and added code snippet related to downloading pdf. Please check.

Comment: could you show the code where and how you print the "title" of the pdf document, giving you: `PDF document.pdf`.

Comment: I am setting the title of pdf file (see full code snippet at question description):  `metadata[PDFDocumentAttribute. titleAttribute] = "title attribute"`

I save this pdf file using `save to files` option (UIActivityController). While saving, the name of pdf file is `PDF Document.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
pdfDocument.documentAttributes?["Title"] = "my title attribute"
```

or

```
pdfDocument.documentAttributes?[PDFDocumentAttribute.titleAttribute] = "my title attribute"
```

Similarly for `PDFDocumentAttribute.subjectAttribute`.

The above will set the `Title` of your document, and when you save it, the `file` name will be whatever `file name` you give it.

EDIT-1: saving the `pdfDocument` to a file with a chosen `file name`.

```
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let unwrappedData = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error ?? Constants.dummyError))
                return
            }
            guard let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: unwrappedData) else {
                completion(.failure(error ?? Constants.dummyError))
                return
            }
            
            // set the Title
            pdfDocument.documentAttributes?[PDFDocumentAttribute.titleAttribute] = "my title attribute"
            
            do {
                // save the document to the given file name ("mydoc.pdf")
                let docURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("mydoc.pdf")  // <-- here file name
                pdfDocument.write(to: docURL)
                print("\n docUrl: \(docURL.absoluteString)\n")
            }
            catch {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
            completion(.success(pdfDocument))
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried to set the `title` attribute. It is not changing the file name

Comment: that's right, changing the `Title` does not change the file name. The `Title` and `File name` are completely different. They have no relation to each other.
To `change` the file name, do it when you save the file (eg. a local file url). 
The file will be given the `file name` you set it, and the `pdfDocument` will still have the `Title` attribute you set it previously.
I have tested this, and it works very well.
Show the code you use to `save` your `pdfDocument` to a file, I can then advise you how to change the name.

Comment: updated my answer with some example code to show how to change the `Title` attribute of the `pdfDocument`, and how to give it a `file name` when you save it.